# get line number which variable is defined in a different file

Tags: python, python-2.3

is it possible for me to get the line number which variable is defined in a different file.
for example:

```
file1.py
x = 5
mylist = [ 1, 2, 3]


file2.py

execfile("file1.py")
# TODO
# get line number of 'x' or 'mylist'
```

I assume each variable is defined only once but just in case what if they defined multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: If they are defined multiple times then the last definition persists. So the question is what do you need this for?

Comment: 'file1.py' is being imported to 'file2.py' using excefile() command (just edited my question).
I would like to know which file x (or mylist) is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly improved version of Ashwini's answer, using the `ast` module and not regular expressions is:

```
import ast

class GetAssignments(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
            print node.id, node.lineno

with open('testing.py') as fin:
    module = ast.parse(fin.read())
    GetAssignments().visit(module)
```

And I think something similar can be used on already compiled objects...

Comment: as I mentioned in my comments. I'd like to avoid reading 'file1.py' since it is already accessible in 'file2.py'.
by the way I'm using python 2.3 so I don't think I have 'with' and 'ast' available

Comment: @user1798187 Here's a radical idea - what asking a question, state all available information... so that's 1) you're using Python 2.3 only, that 2) you already have something from `execfile` (an example source is...), and you'd like a result of....

Comment: @JonClements Hi, Jon. I'm trying to modify this code, but when I add a line `return node.lineno` it won't return anything. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

using `regex`:

try something like this, it will return all the lines wherever it finds  `x = something` :

```
In [25]: with open("fil.py") as f:
    print [index for index,line in enumerate(f) if re.findall(r'(x\s+=)',line)]
   ....:     
[0, 2, 3]
```

where `fil.py` contains:

```
x = 5
mylist = [ 1, 2, 3]
x = 7
x = 8
```

Comment: Thanks but bear in mind that I don't like to read 'file1.py' since this is a python file that is being imported to 'file2.py' using excefile() command (just edited my question)

Comment: @user1798187 and the reason for doing this?

Comment: I don't like to read the 'file1.py' since it is already accessible in 'file2.py'. I can access its members, meaning, see which variables are defined and their values. the only thing I am missing is the line number.
I need the line number mainly to give detailed log report. 
say 'x' must be positive but it is defined as -1 I would like to generate log:
"[Line 5] 'x' is invalid. must be positive. Found '-1'"

Comment: I think then `execfile()` or `import` are not the correct way of doing this as they convert the file into byte code, so you can't fetch the line number from them. You need to read the file with `open()` or may use a parsing module like [configparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)